# Pigeonhole question and generalization

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

Let H be a regular hexagon with side length 1 unit.

(a) Show that if more than 6 points are specied inside H then the points of at least one pair of them are at most 1 unit apart.

(b) State and prove a generalization of the result in (a) to the situation where there are in excess of $2^{2n+1}3$ points inside H.

I did part (a), I solved it using the Pigeonhole Principle. On the other side, I don't understand what part (b) is about. Any suggestions is more that appreciate it!!

Comment: Let $H$ be a regular n-gon with side length 1 unit. show that if more than $2^{2n+1}3$  are specified inside $H$, then atleast one pair of them at most 1 unit apart.

Comment: @GA316  Thank you both, but I still don't get it. $2^{2n+1}3$ are the points, but if I proved it that more than 6 are at most 1 unit apart, what do I have to do for this question?

Comment: @doppz When n =1, then there are 12 points. The distance between then is still at most 1 unit, no?

Comment: use the same idea as (a). enough to prove there is "atleat one pair" which are one unit apart.Use Pigeon Hole Principle.

Comment: @GA316 Drawing the **same** conclusion from a **stronger** assumption, how is that a generalization?

Comment: @GA316 I don't see it... I need to generalize first, so then prove it.

Comment: @bof oops! I thought in (a)we proving for Hexagon and in (b) we are proving for n-gon. I confused by the n in $2^{2n+1}3$. so in (b) also are we working in Hexagon?

Comment: @GA316 I am assuming that it is also in Hexagon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: An equilateral triangle with sides of unit length can be split into $2^{2n}$ triangles of side length $\frac{1}{2^n}$.

As you noticed before, a regular hexagon with side lengths 1 can be split into 6 equilateral triangles of unit length. Thus, a regular hexagon with side lengths 1 can be split into $2^{2n+1}3$ equilateral triangles of side length $\frac{1}{2^n}$.

Now, how can you use the pigeonhole principle to prove a more general result for your part (b)?

Comment: I don't see it.. What I am finding the most difficult is identifying when the PH Principle goes in.

Comment: The use of the PHP is the same as in part (a) which you did. Put more than 7 points in 6 triangles, two points will be in the same triangle. Put more than 24 points in 24 triangles, two points will be in the same triangle.

Comment: And more generally, if you have more than $2^{2n+1}3$ points and $2^{2n+1}3$ triangles, two points will be in the same triangle.

Answer (score 0):

In case $n=0$ you have more than $6$ points in $H$. You solved that by dissecting $H$ into $6$ equilateral triangles of side $1$; by the pigeonhole principal, two of the points must be in the same triangle.

In case $n=1$ you have more than $24$ points in $H$. Now you want to dissect $H$ into $24$ congruent equilateral triangles. You do that by subdividing each of the $6$ triangles into four smaller triangles of side $\frac12$.

Comment: n = 1, then there are more than 12 points, no 24. right?

Comment: it is obvious that the more points there are in a triangle, and the smaller the triangles get, then the closer the points will be with respect to each other.

Comment: If $n=1$ then $2^{2n+1}\cdot3=2^{2\cdot1+1}\cdot3=2^3\cdot3=8\cdot3=24$.

Comment: The idea is to divide the hexagon into a number of little triangles. If you put more points in the hexagon than there are triangles, then **two** points will be in the **same** triangle, so the distance between those two points is less than or equal to the longest side of the triangle.

Comment: sorry, I was thinking $2^{n+1}$