# What Does "less than or equal to 1 apart" Mean?

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

I thought [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/151228/what-does-less-than-or-equal-to-1-apart-mean) question was classified as a word-meaning question. So, does "**1 apart**" mean 1/2 the side of the triangle?

reference:

[image]

Comment: It looks to be referring to a distance of $1$ unit apart.

Comment: @JohnHabert, so this means that the distance between two points at least is 1 unit?

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/545048/pigeonhole-question-and-generalization/545063#545063) for a similar question.

Comment: @Kareem -- no. It means that the distance is **at most** one unit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put five points in this triangles, there will be two distinct points among them with a distance $\le 1$. Or: It is impossible to find five points in this triangle such that all pairwise distances are $>1$. (And yes, as the side length of the triangle, you can replace $1$ with "half the side length" here).

As a hint to the solution, partition the triangle into four suitable parts.

Answer (score 0):

To say that two points are "less than or equal to 1 apart" means that the distance between the two points is less than or equal to 1 unit. Or, more briefly, the distance is at most one unit.

Answer (score 0):

$$\mathrm{dist}\,(x,y)\leqslant1$$